# Need to check answer for Bayes' rule question

Tags: probability

> Suppose that $P(B \mid A_1) = 1/2$ and that $P(B \mid A_2) = 1/4$ where $A_1$ and $A_2$ are two equiprobable events forming a partition of $S$. Then $P(A_1 \mid B)$ is given by
>
> [i] $1/2 \qquad$ [ii] $2/3 \qquad$ [iii] $1/3 \qquad$ **[iv] $\mathbf{3/8} \qquad$** [v] None of the above

For this question the mark scheme answer is 3/8 but using Bayes’ rule, I got the answer to be 2/3. Please could somebody check this for me?

Comment: Your answer is correct; the one marked seems to be for $P(B)$.